# Python27 - Can't access item in data returned from API

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I'm trying to get info from an API:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://URL_for API')
print response.text
```

result:

```
[{"HostName":"","UserName":"test_user","Notes":"","URL":"","Password":"password1"}]
```

But when I try:

```
print response['Password']
```

I get:

> TypeError: 'Response' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

If I try:

```
print response.Password
```

I get:

> AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'Password'

How can I access this value?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `response` is a [Response object](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response) wrapping the actual result. To get the actual data you need the [json method](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content):

```
json_resp = response.json()
```

Then `json_resp` is not going to be a dict, but a **list** containing a dict (see square brackets around the printed result). The correct way to access that will be:

```
json_resp[0]['Password']
```